# How would I set an array of AnyObject.Type objects?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I was trying this last night in various combinations. To my sane mind, this should work perfectly reasonably:

```
var aTest: Array<AnyObject.Type> = [MyObject.Type]
```

As should this:

```
var myTest: AnyObject.Type = MyObject.Type
```

As for that second example, which is a little simpler, I first get the error:

> Expected member name or constructor after type name

And the suggestion to change it to:

```
var myTest: AnyObject.Type = MyObject.Type()
```

Which then simply gives the dead-end error of:

> 'MyObject.Type' is not constructible with '()'

My MyObject is simply set up like so:

```
class MyObject {

}
```

My goal is to subclass MyObject into various different subclasses, all which will be contained within an array, so I could access their class methods and then create an instance of any of them when I choose to.

Comment: p.s. `AnyObject.Type` is better known as `AnyClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the solution was to do this:

```
var myTest: AnyObject.Type = MyObject.self
```

And this:

```
var aTest: Array<AnyObject.Type> = [MyObject.self]
```